# Create time series on hourly basis

Tags: r, time-series

I want to create a time series of 2 years (2016-2017) on an hourly basis with tariff values depending on the time of the year i.e. summer and winter with respect for weekdays, weekends/public holidays.

So far I have create a time_index, the values for 24 hours in summer, the values for 24 hours in winter and the values for 24 hours in the weekend/public holidays.

Here's my code so far:

```
time_index <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00"), 
              to = as.POSIXct("2017-12-31 23:00"), by = "hour")

summer<-c(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,
          1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,0.4)

weeekn_ph<-c(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,
             0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4)

winter<-c(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,1.1,2.3,2.3,2.3,2.3,2.3,2.3,2.3,
          2.3,2.3,2.3,2.3,2.3,2.3,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1)
```

The summer period is effective from 20/3-2016 to 21/9-2016 and the winter period is the rest.

I have a timeseries from 2015 with the same data. Here's a print of the first 48 hours of the year:

```
head(hp, n=48)
             dato tarif
1  01-01-15 00:00   0.4
2  01-01-15 01:00   0.4
3  01-01-15 02:00   0.4
4  01-01-15 03:00   0.4
5  01-01-15 04:00   0.4
6  01-01-15 05:00   0.4
7  01-01-15 06:00   0.4
8  01-01-15 07:00   0.4
9  01-01-15 08:00   0.4
10 01-01-15 09:00   0.4
11 01-01-15 10:00   0.4
12 01-01-15 11:00   0.4
13 01-01-15 12:00   0.4
14 01-01-15 13:00   0.4
15 01-01-15 14:00   0.4
16 01-01-15 15:00   0.4
17 01-01-15 16:00   0.4
18 01-01-15 17:00   0.4
19 01-01-15 18:00   0.4
20 01-01-15 19:00   0.4
21 01-01-15 20:00   0.4
22 01-01-15 21:00   0.4
23 01-01-15 22:00   0.4
24 01-01-15 23:00   0.4
25 02-01-15 00:00   0.4
26 02-01-15 01:00   0.4
27 02-01-15 02:00   0.4
28 02-01-15 03:00   0.4
29 02-01-15 04:00   0.4
30 02-01-15 05:00   0.4
31 02-01-15 06:00   1.1
32 02-01-15 07:00   2.3
33 02-01-15 08:00   2.3
34 02-01-15 09:00   2.3
35 02-01-15 10:00   2.3
36 02-01-15 11:00   2.3
37 02-01-15 12:00   2.3
38 02-01-15 13:00   2.3
39 02-01-15 14:00   2.3
40 02-01-15 15:00   2.3
41 02-01-15 16:00   2.3
42 02-01-15 17:00   2.3
43 02-01-15 18:00   2.3
44 02-01-15 19:00   2.3
45 02-01-15 20:00   1.1
46 02-01-15 21:00   1.1
47 02-01-15 22:00   1.1
48 02-01-15 23:00   1.1
```

The first day of 2015 was a public holiday whereas the second day was a Friday.

I'm pretty rusty with R.

Comment: Why do you turn your data into character? The decimal is ".", not ",".

Comment: Ahhh, sorry because in Denmark we use comma instead of dot. I'll change it.

Comment: Remove the quotes also, it is not necessary

Comment: Done. Still rusty...